# Implement native binder code of c++

Tags: android, android-binder

I have the following code for native binder implementation.

```
#define LOG_TAG "binder_demo"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <utils/RefBase.h>
#include <utils/Log.h>
#include <binder/TextOutput.h>
#include <binder/IInterface.h>
#include <binder/IBinder.h>
#include <binder/ProcessState.h>
#include <binder/IServiceManager.h>
#include <binder/IPCThreadState.h>

using namespace android;
#define INFO(...) \
    do { \
        printf(__VA_ARGS__); \
        printf("\n"); \
        ALOGD(__VA_ARGS__); \
    } while(0)

void assert_fail(const char *file, int line, const char *func, const char *expr) {
    INFO("assertion failed at file %s, line %d, function %s:",
            file, line, func);
    INFO("%s", expr);
    abort();
}
#define ASSERT(e) \
    do { \
        if (!(e)) \
            assert_fail(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, #e); \
    } while(0)

#define PLOG aout

class IDemo : public IInterface {
    public:
        enum {
            ALERT = IBinder::FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION,
            PUSH,
            ADD
        };
        // Sends a user-provided value to the service
        virtual void push(int32_t data) = 0;

        // Sends a fixed alert string to the service
        virtual void alert() = 0;

        // Requests the service to perform an addition and return the result
        virtual int32_t add(int32_t v1, int32_t v2) = 0;

        DECLARE_META_INTERFACE(Demo); // Expands to 5 lines below:

};

// Client
class BpDemo : public BpInterface<IDemo> {
    public:
        BpDemo(const sp<IBinder>& impl) : BpInterface<IDemo>(impl) {
            ALOGD("BpDemo::BpDemo()");
        }

        virtual void push(int32_t push_data) {
            Parcel data, reply;
            data.writeInterfaceToken(IDemo::getInterfaceDescriptor());
            data.writeInt32(push_data);
            aout << "BpDemo::push parcel to be sent:\n";
            data.print(PLOG); endl(PLOG);
            remote()->transact(PUSH, data, &reply);
            aout << "BpDemo::push parcel reply:\n";
            reply.print(PLOG); endl(PLOG);
            ALOGD("BpDemo::push(%i)", push_data);
        }
        virtual void alert() {
            Parcel data, reply;
            data.writeInterfaceToken(IDemo::getInterfaceDescriptor());
            data.writeString16(String16("The alert string"));
            remote()->transact(ALERT, data, &reply, IBinder::FLAG_ONEWAY); // asynchronous call
            ALOGD("BpDemo::alert()");
        }
        virtual int32_t add(int32_t v1, int32_t v2) {
            Parcel data, reply;
            data.writeInterfaceToken(IDemo::getInterfaceDescriptor());
            data.writeInt32(v1);
            data.writeInt32(v2);
            aout << "BpDemo::add parcel to be sent:\n";
            data.print(PLOG); endl(PLOG);
            remote()->transact(ADD, data, &reply);
            ALOGD("BpDemo::add transact reply");
            reply.print(PLOG); endl(PLOG);
            int32_t res;
            status_t status = reply.readInt32(&res);
            ALOGD("BpDemo::add(%i, %i) = %i (status: %i)", v1, v2, res, status);
            return res;
        }
};

 DECLARE_META_INTERFACE(Demo,"Demo"); // Expands to 5 lines below:
// Server
class BnDemo : public BnInterface<IDemo> {

    virtual status_t onTransact(uint32_t code, const Parcel& data, Parcel* reply, uint32_t flags = 0);
};
status_t BnDemo::onTransact(uint32_t code, const Parcel& data, Parcel* reply, uint32_t flags) {
    ALOGD("BnDemo::onTransact(%i) %i", code, flags);
    data.checkInterface(this);
    data.print(PLOG); endl(PLOG);
    switch(code) {
        case ALERT: {
            alert(); // Ignoring the fixed alert string
            return NO_ERROR;
        } break;
        case PUSH: {
            int32_t inData = data.readInt32();
            ALOGD("BnDemo::onTransact got %i", inData);
            push(inData);
            ASSERT(reply != 0);
            reply->print(PLOG); endl(PLOG);
            return NO_ERROR;
        } break;
        case ADD: {
            int32_t inV1 = data.readInt32();
            int32_t inV2 = data.readInt32();
            int32_t sum = add(inV1, inV2);
            ALOGD("BnDemo::onTransact add(%i, %i) = %i", inV1, inV2, sum);
            ASSERT(reply != 0);
            reply->print(PLOG); endl(PLOG);
            reply->writeInt32(sum);
            return NO_ERROR;
        } break;
        default:
            return BBinder::onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);
    }
}
class Demo : public BnDemo {
    virtual void push(int32_t data) {
        INFO("Demo::push(%i)", data);
    }
    virtual void alert() {
        INFO("Demo::alert()");
    }
    virtual int32_t add(int32_t v1, int32_t v2) {
        INFO("Demo::add(%i, %i)", v1, v2);
        return v1 + v2;
    }
};
// Helper function to get a hold of the "Demo" service.
sp<IDemo> getDemoServ() {
    sp<IServiceManager> sm = defaultServiceManager();
    ASSERT(sm != 0);
    sp<IBinder> binder = sm->getService(String16("Demo"));

    // TODO: If the "Demo" service is not running, getService times out and binder == 0.
    ASSERT(binder != 0);
    sp<IDemo> demo = interface_cast<IDemo>(binder);
    ASSERT(demo != 0);
    return demo;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc == 1) {
        ALOGD("We're the service");
        defaultServiceManager()->addService(String16("Demo"), new Demo());
        android::ProcessState::self()->startThreadPool();
        ALOGD("Demo service is now ready");
        IPCThreadState::self()->joinThreadPool();
        ALOGD("Demo service thread joined");
    } else if (argc == 2) {
        INFO("We're the client: %s", argv[1]);
        int v = atoi(argv[1]);
        sp<IDemo> demo = getDemoServ()
        demo->alert();
        demo->push(v);
        const int32_t adder = 5;
        int32_t sum = demo->add(v, adder);
        ALOGD("Addition result: %i + %i = %i", v, adder, sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is how to compile and test it on a android platform. I don't want to build a new binary. What I want is that the code should compile on a running android platform and result should be displayed on a terminal like adb shell.

Comment: [link](http://ebixio.com/blog/2012/07/07/using-android-ipc-binders-from-native-code/) refer to this link, specially the adb shell part.

Comment: [link](http://www.slideshare.net/jserv/android-ipc-mechanism) also you can check this slide(slide no 66) . They some how executed the cpp file through adb shell.

Comment: Actually I want to capture the data that is being passed as parcel through the binder.